# Using jni in Android: UNsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, java-native-interface, header-files, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm new to jni, and I was going over a tutorial to implement a simple native method, but I'm getting an unsatisfiedlinkerror. As far as I know, I followed the steps in the tutorial exactly. Please help me.

Here is the java wrapper code:

```
package com.cookbook.jni;

public class SquaredWrapper {

    // Declare native method (and make it public to expose it directly)
    public static native int squared(int base);

   // Provide additional functionality, that "extends" the native method
   public static int to4(int base)
   {
      int sq = squared(base);
      return squared(sq);
   }

   // Load library
   static {
      System.loadLibrary("squared");
   }
}
```

Here's what my Android.mk file looks like:

> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>
> LOCAL_MODULE    := squared
>   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := squared.c
>
> include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Here's what my .c file looks like:

```
#include "squared.h"
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_edwards_1research_demo_jni_SquaredWrapper_squared
  (JNIEnv * je, jclass jc, jint base)
{
     return (base*base);
}
```

And here is what my .h file looks like:

```
enter code here/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_cookbook_jni_SquaredWrapper */

#ifndef _Included_com_cookbook_jni_SquaredWrapper
#define _Included_com_cookbook_jni_SquaredWrapper
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
* Class:     com_cookbook_jni_SquaredWrapper
* Method:    squared
* Signature: (I)I
*/
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_cookbook_jni_SquaredWrapper_squared
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your JNI signature doesn't match. In your .c file, change:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_edwards_1research_demo_jni_SquaredWrapper_squared
```

to

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_cookbook_jni_SquaredWrapper_squared
```

Generally there are two ways to "glue" native C through JNI to a Java function. The first is what you're attempting to do here, that is use a predetermined signature that JNI will recognize and associate with your appropriate Java code. The second is to pass function pointers, signatures, and Java class names into JNI when you include the library.

Here's the second method that would bind the native function to the appropriate Java code (this would be your .c file):

```
#include "squared.h"
#include <jni.h>

static const char* SquaredWrapper = "com/cookbook/jni/SquaredWrapper";

jint squared(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jint base) {
     return (base*base);
}

// Methods to register for SquaredWrapper
static JNINativeMethod SquareWrapperMethods[] = {
        {"squared", "(I)I", squared}
};

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    JNIEnv* env;
    if ( (*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
        return JNI_ERR;

    jclass class = (*env)->FindClass(env, SquaredWrapper);
    (*env)->RegisterNatives(env, class, SquaredWrapperMethods, sizeof(SquaredWrapperMethods)/sizeof(SquaredWrapperMethods[0]));

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

void JNI_OnUnload(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    JNIEnv* env;
    if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
        return;

    jclass class = (*env)->FindClass(env, SquaredWrapper);
    (*env)->UnregisterNatives(env, class);

    return;

}
```

It's a good deal longer but it gives you a lot more flexibility when binding native code. The definition for squared and the includes are as you would expect. on the 4th line, the static const char* SquaredWrapper is an escaped string with the fully qualified package name of the class you want to bind squared to. Near the bottom are the JNI_OnLoad and JNI_OnUnLoad functions that take care of binding and unbinding the functions on library load and unload. The last piece is the JNINativeMethod array. This array contains as each entry an array of size 3 whose components are the Java name of the method as a const char*, the JNI signature of the Java method, and the native C function pointer to bind to that method. The JNI function signature tells the environment the argument list format and return value of the Java function. The format is "(Arg1Arg2Arg3...)Ret", so a function that takes an int and double and returns a float would have a signature of "(ID)F", and a function that takes no arguments and returns void would be "()V". I use this handy cheat sheet to remember most of the shorthand:

http://dev.kanngard.net/Permalinks/ID_20050509144235.html

Good luck :)

**Edit:** Oh, BTW, you'll likely want to add the signatures for JNI_OnLoad and JNI_UnOnLoad to your header, and change the name of your native function prototype to reflect the new .c file.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel stupid. I just copied and pasted the c file from the tutorial, but I used a different package name than he did. Hence the mismatch. I haven't heard of that second way. Could post a link to somewhere where I can read more about it? Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, the method I prefer is to use JNI_OnLoad: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/jni.html#native_libraries and keep an array of all my functions and signatures. Lemme write up some example code and I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an obscure case, but if you get an access violation in your native code, Android will cover up the thrown exception and throw the error you got. In my case, the native code threw an access violation but Java kept running. It then tried to call a JNI method on the crashed NDK.

To find the access violation, I ended up moving the offending JNI method to another IDE to debug.

I hope this saves someone the amount of time it took me to figure this out.